# JavaScript permalink URL

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is there JavaScript code that can change the title to a URL?

Example: title → Download the Latest Anime.

I want to change it to → download-the-latest-anime

Comment: You're talking about two very different aspects of HTML. Title is what appears in the title bar of the browser, and the URL is the address used to access the website.

Comment: "download-the-latest-anime" is not a url. It is very unclear what exactly you trying to achieve (and where you stuck writing code)...

Answer (score 0):

Lodash's [`.kebabCase`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#kebabCase) converts to that particular format:

```js
console.log(
    _.kebabCase(document.title)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Lodash function for doing this. Lodash is a JavaScript library that consists of various utility functions.

First, you need to install it using `npm`:

```
npm i lodash
```

Then, you need to import it into your file.

```js
const _ = require("lodash")

title = _.kebabCase("Download The Latest Anime")
```

This will automatically convert "Download The Latest Anime" to "download-the-latest-anime"

[Lodash Docs Link](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#kebabCase)